# Как проапгрейдить Delphi Starter 10.1upd2 (Berlin) до 10.2 (Tokyo)?

Tags: delphi

Наверное, уже многие знают, что вышла новая версия Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, основной изюминкой которой, стал такой долгообещаный и жданный Linux компилятор (УРА,УРА!).

https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/rad-studio-10-2-tokyo

и

https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/whats-new-in-10-2-tokyo

Отступление:

> Вот тут, совершенно (пока) бесплатно, можно скачать Starter версию, и
>   получить подписку и доступ к внут.ресурсам сайта
>   https://www.embarcadero.com/ru/products/delphi/starter/promotional-download
>   (аналогично http://habrahabr.net/thread/372) регистритесь, получаете
>   на почту ключ и скачиваете установщик. При запуске (откл.фаэр) - он
>   еще много чего затащит и через ключик проделаете регистрацию. **Отличия
>   версий читайте на сайте (нововведения не во всех!)**. НО! Зарегеную бесплатную версию думаю
>   *желательно* всем иметь :)
>
> Конешна, в рукаве всегда есть бесплатный Лазарус
>   (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus) за что кста благодарность
>   большая его разрабам, но тут...

**Вопрос:**

Была установлена аналогичным образом 10.1u2(berlin). При скачивании и уст.новой версии она старую не видит и ставится рядом.
Как апгрейдить старую на новую версию? На полных версиях последнее время все снести рекомендуют. А тут на бесплатной - тоже нет возможности?

Comment: Такого рода обновления не предусмотрены. Новая версия всегда ставится отдельно и требует своей лицензии.

Comment: В полных версиях я это видел, да. Теперь у них подход другой. Но тут - козявка на гиг, по сравнению с полной, тоже без вариантов?

Comment: 1. с основных версий вроде как на -2 пошло, что апгрейд не желателен (так и есть), а только переустановка. не припомните где почитать об этом. 2. отдельный вопрос: если коммент как ответ подходит - то как вопрос закрыть, указав что коммент ответом будет?

Comment: `долгообещаный и жданный Lunix компилятор` доступный только в enterprize версии. Да и разработка под мобильные платформы - только от Professional и выше. А на стартере - win32 и всё.

Comment: >> долгообещаный и жданный Lunix компилятор доступный только в enterprize версии. Да и разработка под мобильные платформы - только от Professional и выше >>писалось же: Отличия версий читайте на сайте. Да, к сожалению. Но не про это речь. 1. Заиметь лиц. версию. 2. Вот вопрос как ее апгрейдить, Видимо никак, только новую ставить и все комп. переставлять. Да как ответ норм (и ранее знали, правда только для полной версии ent\pro), спасиб.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждая версия Delphi ставится отдельно.

В этом есть свои плюсы - вы всегда можете поработать и скомпилировать проект в доступных прошлых версиях.

Если вы хотите удалить старую версию - так и удаляйте.

Comment: и минусы, если у вас были компоненты :)

Comment: @Gu. Минус вы имеете ввиду в том что надо заново ставить компоненты? При апгрейде было бы так же, т.к. язык и среда развивается и в каждой новой версии новые изменения.